# How Read undersubmission Request Property from CA

Tags: c#-3.0, x509certificate2, pki, pkcs#7, certificate-authority

I used this code to generate undersubmissionRequest in CA

```
nDisposition = ICertRequest.Submit(Flag, Request, sAttributes, sServerConfig);
```

and when nDisposition == 5 (CR_DISP_UNDER_SUBMISSION) I use this code:

```
 CARequestID = ICertRequest.GetRequestId();
 DespositCode = ICertRequest.RetrievePending(CARequestID , sServerConfig);
```

but I want to Get  undersubmisionRequest PublicKey. How can I get it?

Comment: You can't get it through `ICertRequest` interface. You have to use `ICertView` interface (requires `certadm.dll`) to get the DB row for your pending request. If you have your CSR, you can extract public key from there rather than bothering with `ICertView`.

Comment: Thankyou, I used ICertView and my problem is solved